# How to make a neural network generalizes better?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I designed a neural network model with large number of output predicted by softmax function. However, I want categorize all the outputs into 5 outputs without modifying the architecture of other layers. The model performs well in the first case but when I decrease the number of output it loses accuracy and get a bad generalization. My question is: Is there a method to make my model performs well even if there is just 5 outputs? for example: adding dropout layer before output layer, using other activation function, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should work if we update the last Softmax units and **update the weight of the last layer accordingly**.

I have tried this with MNIST digit and seems to work

```py
#Let's assume "model" is the trained model on 10 outputs

saved_model = model.save('/content/model.h5')
model_reload = keras.models.load_model('/content/model.h5')

#Create model_2 with 5 output
from keras.models import Sequential
model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential()
for layer in model_reload.layers[:-1]: # go through until last layer
    model_2.add(layer)
model_2.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

#Get the last layer weight, this is where you have to take care while slicing the weight matrix depending on which 5 Class you are retaining
#We are taking digits (0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
wb=[]
for layer in model_reload.layers:
    if 'Dense' in str(layer):
        if layer.units==10:
            w=layer.get_weights()[0][:,::2] ##Note this slicing weight
            b=layer.get_weights()[1][::2] ##Note this slicing of bias
            wb.append(w)
            wb.append(b)
model_2.layers[-1].set_weights(wb)

##Test
dataset_new = dataset_new[(dataset_new.label % 2 = 0)] #Only even digits
x = dataset_new.iloc[:,1:]
y = dataset_new.iloc[:,0]

###Normalize the data
x = x/255

y_pred = model_2.predict_classes(x)
y_pred = y_pred * 2 #Model will predict 0-4(This multiply is too map it to 0,2,4,6,8

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y,y_pred)
```

> *0.9514600845439969*, **It is better than the base accuracy**

You may check the same in this [Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s2oFIL24YBGZ0dYlQAbpGqYeX8wc1YYP?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your dataset is labelled properly in 5 distinct classes from 0 to 4 and no more.
Then add dropout layer in between each layer with prob of 0.1 and gradually increase till 0.5 until you find  a good val score.
In your optimizer add weight decay term with value around 0.1.
Find some appropriate regularizer for your data type online.